# Choosing stabilizers on the honeycomb code

Tags: error-correction, surface-code

In the paper ["Dynamically Generated Logical Qubits"](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2021-10-19-564/), The authors state that the stabilizer group includes "two homologically nontrivial cycles
wrapping different directions of the torus".

If we look at the surface code on an torus, the logical operators $\hat{X}_L$, $\hat{Z}_L$ are those operators - they wrap the torus in different directions. To my understanding, if we included those operators in the stabilizer group then we have less degrees of freedom, and we could not encode a logical qubit on it.

Why can't we just do the same on the honeycomb code? If we don't include these operators in the stabilizer group for the honeycomb code, can we get a degree of freedom that can be used for a logical qubit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X and Z observables of a qubit must anticommute. If you compute the commutators of the Pauli terms forming those two cycles, you will find that they commute. Therefore they don't form a logical qubit.

For example, here is the vertical cycle (in black) and the horizontal cycle (in magenta) of a 4x6 patch with periodic boundaries. The vertical and horizontal terms disagree at two locations. Two is even, so they commute.

[image]

These cycles actually correspond to the product of the observables of the logical qubits in the system. One is $X_{L1}X_{L2}$ while the other is $Z_{L1}Z_{L2}$. That's why they commute, and why you have to dig deeper to to find the actual logical qubits being hinted at by these cycles.